# AngularJS ui.router modal templateURL/template as a directive

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-modal

I want to create a customizable general modal, within ui.router, and i`m using ui.router.modal and ui.bootstrap references as well. I would like something like the following snippet:

```
{          
          name: 'parentpage.modal',
          url: "/modal",
          onEnter: ['$stateParams', '$state', '$uibModal', function ($stateParams, $state, $uibModal) {
            $uibModal.open({
              template: "<mydirective config-one="a", config-two="b"></mydirective>"
              // no need for "controller:", as it is solved with the directive itself
}
```

Is it possible to do it, or is there any workaround about it? I will have many modals, so i want to avoid code duplication.

[Reference for the uibModal](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal)

Comment: it should probably be in a Service/Factory where you can just customise certain parts of the modal, e.g. : `template: my_template`, which you pass in as a parameter